# substitution model scala

Tags: scala

I am doing a scala course at the moment. There is some discussion regarding the substitution model.  It states:

```
def f(x1,...,xn) = B; ... f(v1,..., vn)
then
def f(x1,...,xn) = B; ... [v1/x1,...,vn/xn]B

Here, [v1/x1,...,vn/xn]B means:
The expression B in which all occurrences of xi have been replaced
by vi.
[v1/x1,...,vn/xn] is called a substitution
```

I have two questions here:

Is there any big concept here?  *To me it is just saying `plug the values in` in a fancy way.*
The notation being used for the substitution `[v1/x1,...,vn/xn]` is this used anywhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it does essentially say "plug the values in" in a fancy way. It's still a good idea to have a formal and unambiguous notation for it, and in fact this is a standard notation in theoretical computer science (and not something the lecturer of your course made up).

In particular, "plug the values in" becomes more complicated in situation where you have to be worried about variables being bound that should be free and the other way round. If you are interested in details, grab a textbook with a good introduction of lambda calculus.

Comment: thanks according to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus  := is used for substitution. The lecturer on this course uses / for it.  I wonder why?

Comment: In the literature for first-order logic and term rewriting, the `/` is, in my recollection, more common than `:=`.

Comment: @Randall Schulz Thanks do you have any reference for that? Thanks.

Comment: There's a mountain of literature on this and related topics. "Term Rewriting and All That" by Baader and Nipkow is a good introduction.